# ZendFramework Google Contacts

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-contacts-api

I am using the following

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html

to authenticate to Google and retrieve a users contacts. However I would prefer this system to use Google's oAuth integration.

What is the easiest way to do this or a simple example?

Essentially I want to modify this

```
      $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cp');
  $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
  $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

  // perform query and get feed of all results
  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query(
    'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  $query->maxResults = 1000;
  $query->setParam('sortorder', 'descending');
  $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

Such that it now uses oauth2 such that a user never has to give their email or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following tutorial which resolved my problem.

http://leandroardissone.com/post/1330339821/google-contacts-php